# JUnit Test Cases for Web Services

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, junit

I need to test my REST Web Service in Eclipse using JUnit test cases. How can I proceed? Is it similar to normal Java classes test cases.

Services:

```
@Path("/regionService")
public class RegionService {

@GET
@Path("getRegions")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getRegions(@QueryParam("parentTenancyID") int parentTenancyID) throws CustomFault{
    String result = null;
    RegionServiceImpl implObj = new RegionServiceImpl();
    if(parentTenancyID!=0){
        try{
            result = implObj.getRegionServiceDetails(parentTenancyID);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
   }
}
```

Implementation:

```
    public class RegionServiceImpl {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public String getRegionServiceDetails(int parentTenancyID) {

    String result = null;
    Logger fLogger = FatalLoggerClass.logger;
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String regionQ = "select a.tenancy_id, a.tenancy_name from TenancyEntity a where Parent_Tenancy_ID=" +parentTenancyID+" ";
    Query query = session.createQuery(regionQ);

    try{
        Iterator iterator = query.list().iterator();
        Object[] resultQ = null;
        HashMap<Integer,String> regionMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            resultQ = (Object[]) iterator.next();
            int tenancyId = (Integer) resultQ[0];
            String TenancyName =  (String) resultQ[1];
            regionMap.put(tenancyId, TenancyName);
        }
        jsonObj.putAll(regionMap);
        jsonArray.add(jsonObj);
        result = jsonArray.toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
        fLogger.fatal("Exception :"+e);
    }finally{
        if(session.getTransaction().isActive()){
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }if(session.isOpen()){
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

I want to check whether the JSON response from the service will be equal to the expected value.

Comment: are you using spring?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebClient of JaxRS for it
Refer to following document, it will show you sample tests

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAXRS+Testing